# scikit learn kernel ridge regression produces very different result using linear kernel than simple linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

My understanding of the kernel regression is when using linear kernel for ridge regression with no penalty, results should be similar to linear regression. somehow in the toy example linear regression has much better Rsq. part of the problem I think is SK is using sample space for the kernel matrix instead of the smaller of sample and feature space and in this case feature space is much smaller. how do I "fix" the issue or maybe I have done something wrong - a newbie to kernel regression. linear kernel regression has around -3 score and linear regression score is about 50%

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels
import numpy as np


diab = load_diabetes()
X, y = shuffle(diab.data, diab.target)
X_train, X_test = X[:1000, :], X[100:, :]
y_train, y_test = y[:1000], y[100:]

# krr = KernelRidge(kernel='polynomial', degree=2, coef0=1)
# krr = KernelRidge(kernel='rbf', degree=2, coef0=0)
krr = KernelRidge(kernel='linear', alpha=0.0001)
# krr = KernelRidge(kernel='laplacian')

kernel_train = np.dot(X_train, X_train.T)  # linear kernel

# krr.fit(kernel_train, y_train)
krr.fit(X_train, y_train)

#kernel_test = np.dot(X_test, X_train[svc.support_, :].T)

# kernel_test = np.dot(X_test, X_train.T)
# y_pred = krr.predict(kernel_test)
y_pred = krr.predict(X_test)
# krr.score(kernel_test, y_test), krr.score(kernel_train, y_train)
krr.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, sklearn `KernelRidge()` implementation does not support intercept. Try `LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)` and you should get similarly poor R2. Plot your targets against predictions and you'll see it actually predicts OK, except the prediction is zero centered.

What can you do?

Easy approximation: preprocess your target to zero center it, or estimate the intercept from the mean target values.

Hard way: `KernelCenterer()`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import KernelCenterer
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

kernel_train = X_train @ X_train.T # That's what linear kernel does.
centerer = KernelCenterer()
kernel_train_centered = centerer.fit_transform(kernel_train)

clf = KernelRidge(alpha=0.0001, kernel="precomputed")
clf.fit(kernel_train_centered, y_train - y_train.mean())

kernel_test = X_test @ X_train.T
y_pred = clf.predict(kernel_test)

intercept = y_train.mean() - centerer.K_fit_rows_ @ clf.dual_coef_

y_pred += intercept

r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the answer by @dx2-66 is incorrect, in particular the correction to the intercept is wrong.

See for example the discussion here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21840

If you center the matrix during training you should also center it when predicting. Using the `KernelCenterer` object from sklearn, you can obtain a `kernel_test_centered` as:

```python
kernel_test_centered = centerer.transform(kernel_test)
```

and then use the mean of `y_train` as the intercept. That is:

```python
from sklearn.preprocessing import KernelCenterer
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

kernel_train = X_train @ X_train.T # That's what linear kernel does.
centerer = KernelCenterer()
kernel_train_centered = centerer.fit_transform(kernel_train)

clf = KernelRidge(alpha=0.0001, kernel="precomputed")
clf.fit(kernel_train_centered, y_train - y_train.mean())

kernel_test = X_test @ X_train.T
kernel_test_centered = centerer.transform(kernel_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(kernel_test_centered)

intercept = y_train.mean()

y_pred += intercept

r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
```